# A quick overview of smartphone application development?

Tags: smartphone

What is smart phone development?  I know this is a very broad question, so I'm looking for good websites to begin my research.

A lot of people have asked me if I am a Smart Phone developer.  I say no because I'm not really sure what that means. I don't even own a cell phone.  (I'm a very late adopter of technology).  Do they mean making a blog viewable on a smart phone or do they mean making frivolous iPhone games?

If I were to become a Smart Phone developer, what do I need to know?  What hardware device and software framework should I develop and test on to ensure I reach the widest possible audience?  What's the current trend with smart phones?

Anyone know a good and concise resource that gives an overview of this entire discipline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smart phone is a [very broad term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smartphone). But generally you are smart phone developer if you are developing applications for last generation "smart" phones. If that is iPhone - you are Objective C developer developing apps for iPhone platform, if Android - then you are Java developer, etc. The key is - you are writing code that runs on the specific platform with intent of providing additional services for mobile phone users